# Remove single characters in sql records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on importing some files and I noticed that some of the email addresses are prefixed with a comma.
Eg: `,abc@abc.com`

In a table with 1500 emails, I've found that 700+ of these have this issue.
How would I update them so that the comma is removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
  SET Email = STUFF(Email, 1, 1, '')
  WHERE Email LIKE ',%';
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn=RIGHT(YourColumn,LEN(YourColumn)-1)
    WHERE LEFT(YourColumn,1)=','
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know they always start with a `,`:

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET SomeColumn = SUBSTRING(SomeColumn, 2, 4000)
WHERE SomeColumn LIKE ',%';
```

Otherwise you could do this to get rid of **all** `,` no matter where they appear. Note that here adding a `WHERE SomeColumn LIKE '%,%'` clause might adversely affect performance.

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET SomeColumn = REPLACE(SomeColumn, ',', '');
```

Comment: Probably should add a `WHERE SomeColumn LIKE ',%'`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET email = SUBSTRING(email, 2, 1000) WHERE email LIKE ",%";
```

The `%` is a wildcard, so this will only match those fields that start with a comma.